# Fabric crashes appear only on "Launch status"

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm trying Fabric/Crashlytics in my app but I don't understand this behavior

I simulate a crash but I can only see the right number of crashes on the "Launch Status" page (here 5 crashes)

[image]

But if I select the same build from the Chashlytics home I don't have any crashes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When viewing your list of crashes in Crashlytics, always study three things:  1) Is it filtered to a specific build or not.  2) Is it filtered to the right event type or not (Crashes, Non-fatals, or All).  3) Is it filtered to a narrower than max time range or not (i.e. crank it up to "last 90 days" or maybe an even bigger custom range).

Looks like your list is just for your build 7.6.0. I can't see what time range you have it set to.

Crashlytics web page tries to remember your last used settings in these regards - so when you change them temporarily while studying one issue, then tomorrow you come back in expecting to be seeing everything, it'll still be stuck on your narrowed down filter.  Drives me nuts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately didn't help.
The list is filtered for one single build and the time filter is set to "last 90 days".

Comment: And you are sure your missing crash issues are for that specific build?

Comment: So I just looked at my own app's Launch Status screen.  That screen is claiming there are 0 crashes for that release (my latest release) which I know isn't correct.  I don't know what that 0 crashes is trying to be based on..maybe it's just for the last day or something.  Anyhow, if you click on the link at the bottom right in first white box that says "All issues for <your build number>"  it'll take you to your issues.  Hope this helps!

Comment: for me is the other way around. Is the "All issues for <>" that says that there are 0 crashes (and I know is false) while the "Launch Status screen" reports 5 crashes, but unfortunately doesn't report anything else.

Comment: Is the second popup at top set to Crashes?

Comment: to "all events". I edited the post including the whole page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152177/discussion-between-ignazioc-and-smartcat).

Comment: I have the same problem. I can see a crash on Launch status but not a crash in the main page. Is this just a delay or a bug ?